# Hybris search page facet filters limited in number.

Tags: solr, facet, sap-commerce-cloud

On a listing page on Hybris the number of options within a facet filter is limited to 50 (for example, if there are more than 50 colours to filter by then only 50 will be displayed at one time).

This is proving a problem on my system when all larger "View all" listing pages are used as important filter options are being dropped off of longer lists.

I have search all over the system but I can't seem to find how to extend this limiter number upwards. I hope I'm not asking an obvious question (or just can't see the wood through the trees) but I'd spent days looking for this. Where can I find this setting in my Hybris system?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your limit by adding this property to either in your core extension project.properties file or local.properties file.

`facet.limit.default = 500`

If you define it as -1, then this will become unlimited.